# Why 'git log' is empty even if log file exists?

Tags: git

`git log` does not produces anything even if though "`.git/logs/refs/heads`" does contain the log entries of recent commits.

System:
I uninstalled and reinstalled the git in my ubuntu installation.

```
Linux ap 3.0.0-17-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 8 20:45:39 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Does `git rev-list` give any output?

Comment: Are you somehow using `less -F` as the pager command? On some platforms, `less -F` outputs nothing if the input is small enough to fit on a page. Dropping `-F` or adding `-X` fixes the problem. What happens if you `git log | cat`?

Answer (score 6):

I got the same error. The problem was that I defined a default pager at a wrong location in my `.bashrc`:

```
export PAGER=/usr/bin/more
```

Running `git log` returned no output. I changed the location to `/bin/more` and it got fixed.

Comment: It worked for me. I ran "which more" and then set PAGER to that directory.

Answer (score 3):

`git log` does not relate to ".git/logs/". `git log` reads ".git/refs/"

`git reflog` reads ".git/logs/", which is to record when the tip of branches are updated.

Comment: Below is my refs structure and its content:

    ap refs # find
    .
    ./remotes
    ./remotes/origin
    ./remotes/origin/HEAD
    ./heads
    ./heads/master
    ./tags
    ap refs # cat ./remotes/origin/HEAD ./heads/master
    ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
    e239654193132ee1f030be82d895a695f8657df0

Answer (score 0):

Try to clone again your repo and see if the error persist.

Make sure you don't have `GIT_DIR` or `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variables defined, or otherwise git log wouldn't operate on the git repo you would think it is.

Make sure there is no alias for `git`, or (for that matter) no *git* alias for '`log`'.

Comment: both .gitconfig as well as regular aliases do not have git or log defined and echo $GIT_DIR $GIT_WORK_TREE is empty

Comment: @user530302 and another `git clone` produces the same empty `git log`?

Answer (score 0):

As Diego Pino said, the problem can be a git core.pager setting related.

I'm writing this because I had the same issue but the case was different. After following a tip to setup an empty value in the `git core.pager` settings section I've lost a possibility to use the `git log`, I mean the output of the command was empty. The purpose of this setting was to not use any pager and just print everything to stdout but something gone wrong. It was something like this in the `.gitconfig`:

```
[core]
    pager = " "
```

The solution could be to set a `core.pager` setting in `.gitconfig` globally (in your user's home folder `.gitconfig` file) or in the context of the whole system (in /etc/gitconfig), respectively:

```
git config --global core.pager more
```

or

```
sudo git config --system core.pager more
```

I prefer `more` as a pager for long output, but the default pager in my git installation was `less` - choose which is relevant to you.